# How to add required attribute to wp_login_form fields?

Tags: wp-login-form

I create a new form in wp header using function wp_login_form(), but form fields are not set required attribute. How to add required to field?

Comment: You can use javascript for enforcing required validation.

Comment: yes its done! using      $("#user_login").attr({"placeholder" : "User Name", "required": "required"}); similarly for password field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#user_login").attr({"placeholder" : "User Name", "required": "required"});
```